# Will the Chaos Elemental spawn above ground

Tags: terraria-mobile

I recently heard a tip that in the mobile version of Terraria, illuminant slimes and bats spawn much more frequently in the underground hallow, obstructing the spawn of Chaos Elementals. I was wondering, if I built a large, enclosed area of pearl stone on the surface, would Chaos Elementals spawn? And if not, what is the best way to farm them in the mobile version of Terraria? I have attempted to place pearl stone blocks in a line in the jungle, but all that spawns is pixies and illuminant bats.[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick [Google Search](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Chaos_Elemental) shows that Chaos Elementals spawn in the Underground Hallow. That same page also advices

> On the Mobile version, Illuminant Bats and Illuminant Slimes are overabundant in the Underground Hallow, and will block nearly all Chaos Elemental spawns. This can be alleviated by making an area of Pearlstone or Pearlsand outside of the Underground Hallow, so Chaos Elementals can spawn unobstructed.

This works because

> Chaos Elementals will only spawn on top of Pearlstone or Pearlsand Blocks. They can do so even if the player is not specifically in a hallowed biome.

Comment: So it would still be made underground, just not in the underground hallow?

Comment: @JunHayakawa Correct

Comment: Wait I'm sorry I still don't understand. If you built a pearl stone enclosure underground, wouldn't illuminant bats and slimes still spawn? I'm sorry if I don't get it.

Comment: From what I understand, it's suggesting to have some Pearlstone and Pearlsand, but not enough to change the biome to Hallow.

Comment: I had simply placed down a 1 by 15 line of pearl stone along the ground when the underground hallow soundtrack started and illuminant bats appeared

Comment: You were too close to natural Hallow. Find an area with no Hallow nearby.

Comment: I'm sorry for troubling you but I'm absolutely sure there was no hallow within at least 500 blocks. Again, I'm very sorry you have to keep explaining.

Comment: The Hallow requires 100 blocks, 15 are not enough. If the biome changed, there must've been 100 Hallow blocks. Try a different spot.

Comment: I will now attempt it in the jungle, which I am absolutely sure has never been touched by hallow.

Comment: This seems to be working, except for the fact that all that spawns are illuminant bats and pixies

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61441/discussion-between-danmakugrazer-and-jun-hayakawa).